What is the cause of Argentinian economic decline in the 20th century?
Based on this paper that I am currently reading, https://latinaer.springeropen.com/articles/10.1007/s40503-017-0050-9 it seems to me that the issues was Argentinian gov't enacting ISI, part of which was high tariffs and export taxes, which disregarded Argentinian comparative advantage in agricultural and agro-manufactures production in favor of creating SOE in rubber and other manufacturing.
What I want to understand is why did the gov't take this course and why at the same time did the country start to export its manufactured goods, how were they competitive in the global market considering it was not their competitive advantage and how did it contribute to the stagnation and decline of the Argentinian economy? (Also what lessons can be learned from their experience?)

According to the Maddison Project Database 2023 a leading source of historical economic data, Argentinian GDP per capita, measured in 2011 dollars, grew from 4,583 in 1900 to 14,369 in 2000.  If these figures are even approximately correct, there was no absolute decline, only relative decline compared to many other countries which grew faster.
